# Mongoose schema validation is not working with Fawn

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I'm working on a MEAN app and trying to implement transactions like behavior to MongoDB using FAWN. I'm using mongoose library. When I use fawn, then data is sort of skipping schema conditions like min: 1 for sellingPrice. However, I'm using { useMongoose: true } in run as well.

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Fawn = require('fawn');    
    Fawn.init(mongoose);

    //Function code is as follow

        var task = Fawn.Task();
        let item = await Item.findById(req.params.id);

        task.update('items', {_id: item._id}, {type: req.body.type, name: req.body.name, sku: req.body.sku, openingStock: req.body.openingStock, availableStock: req.body.availableStock, purchasePrice: req.body.purchasePrice, sellingPrice: req.body.sellingPrice, profitMargin: req.body.profitMargin, reorderLevel: req.body.reorderLevel, preferredVendor: req.body.preferredVendor});
        task.update('items', {_id: item._id}, {sellingPrice: -50});//This line should fail because min value for sellingPrice is 1
        task.run({ useMongoose: true })
            .then(function(){res.json(item);})
            .catch(function(error){res.json({error: {"message": error}});});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a number of similar issues with the update, but in the end, the following worked:

```
try {
  await new Fawn.Task()
  .update('collection', 
               { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) } , 
               { name: 'test', desc: 'description })
  .run({useMongoose: true});
} 
catch(err) { console.log(err); }
```

Comment: HOW TO FIX THIS WARNING:
`(node:57487) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.`